# Can't seem to get Select2 to run

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to test out Select2 by following the guide they've provided on their site (https://select2.github.io/). What I basically came up with is including the URI in the html file as well as a simple drop down menu that allows the user to select two states. However when trying to run this, Select2 does not seem to be implementing at all. Was wondering if I am missing something?

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
</script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a silly mistake...did you remember to include jQuery as well?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```